# Alien survives crash, dies from medicine

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, first-contact

This is an old (1950's or 60's?) short story, possibly Soviet or European author. An alien ship crashes near an isolated village (might be a fishing village?). One alien survives the crash but is badly injured. The town doctor tries to help, but doesn't think until too late that the sulfa-infused bandages might be a bad idea - the sulfa kills the alien.

I don't remember where I read this but I'm pretty sure it's not from either of Asimov's *Soviet Science Fiction* collections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Harry Harrison](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?28), [Rescue Operation](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55380).

> Fishers found an astronaut who has dropped to the bottom of sea. When he is rescued it is discovered that he is an alien. Everything doesn't go well, though.

Yes, sulfanilamide bandages kill the alien. The story is located at the coast of Istria, then a part of Yugoslavia.

You can find the whole story on Google Books.

Comment: Harry Harrison, always good for a twist ending...

Comment: I do believe that's the one. Thanks!